# JavaScript if statement test for one or the other but not both

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Hello fellow StackOverflowers. I'm have a brain fart right now, and I cannot seem to figure this out.

I have the following code

```
if ((n % 3 === 0 || n % 5 === 0) &&( n % 3 !== 0 && n % 5 !== 0))
    {
        return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Basically I need to test if the number is a multiple of 3 || 5 but not a multiple of both.

However when I enter any number I enter (whether it is multiple of 3 || 5 || both) the test always fails. I would have thought this was able to be performed in one statement.

This code though does work fine.

```
if (n % 3 === 0 || n % 5 === 0)
{
    if( n % 3 === 0 && n % 5 === 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else {
       return true;
    }
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

But I'm wondering what I am missing in the first test. I'd like all the test to be in one like, but like I said I'm having a brain fart and cannot figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is divisible by both 3 and 5, it'll be divisible by 15.

Please try the following condition

```
if ((n % 3 === 0 || n % 5 === 0) && ( n % 15 !== 0))
```

Comment: +1 I liked the XOR answer the best, BUT I don't think it has the readability that this answer provides.  This answer is a good balance of concise yet readable, which I think makes it preferable.  **ALSO**, @Chris please tell me you are going to **add a comment above this code** that says something to the effect that you're checking for a multiple of 3 or 5 but not both.  Not having that comment would leave this code VERY cryptic (not impossible to decipher, just annoying....)

Comment: Apparently had severe tunnel vision that I didn't realize that 15 would be a test against both.

Comment: @Sam A comment is already in place, to that exact respect, I don't want someone stumbling across this and waste a bunch of time trying to figure out what I'm doing.

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation, folks!

Answer (score 9):

You can use the XOR operator, alternatively

```
return  (n % 3 === 0 ^ n % 5 === 0);
```

Comment: True...  It doesn't work.  `n % 3 === 0 ^ n % 5 === 0` does though.  I wish I had thought of using XOR when I read the Q.  Definitely the way to go.  Although...  It's not often I see it in code.  I wonder how readable others would find it.

Comment: my bad, just added a not-equals instead of an equals. It should work now.

Comment: This produces a bitwise XOR, not a logical one. If you like terse voodoo, try `!(n % 3) !== !(n % 5)` . But that kind of code better not find its way to production.

Comment: @Chad Try again with updated answer.  If still fails, what are you trying?  This seems to work fine for me (testing in Firebug).

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I am new to Javascript and I was not aware of the XOR operator, so this will be something cool to read up on.

Comment: +1 because the question is literally asking for an XOR operation. In Node and WebKit `true ^ true === 0` and `true ^ false === 1`, so it does depend on coercion of numerics to booleans, but I still think this is the "most correct" answer.

Comment: @Sam The updated version works fine ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QpL8e/1/)). I removed my comment, and changed to +1

Answer (score 4):

change

```
if ((n % 3 === 0 || n % 5 === 0) &&( n % 3 !== 0 && n % 5 !== 0))
```

to

```
if ((n % 3 === 0 || n % 5 === 0) && !(n % 3 === 0 && n % 5 === 0))
```

The first part of your logic is to determine if the number in question is a multiple of 3 or 5 whereas the second SHOULD be about wether only one of them is.  So...  I changed the second part to see if both match it and then I NOT'ed that.

Comment: I did not think to add the ! in front of the second test case, that would have solved my issue.

Comment: @Chris I changed the second part in two ways:  **1.)** I checked that both 3 and 5 were multiples (rather than checking to see if both were NOT multiples as your original Q had).  **2.)** I NOT'ed that result.  Looks like you got a lot of good answers.  SO is a cool site.  Always amazes me how competitive it is to answer a Q.

Answer (score 2):

It should be: `if ((n % 3 === 0 || n % 5 === 0) &&( n % 3 !== 0 || n % 5 !== 0))`

Answer (score 1):

```
return (n % 3 === 0  && !(n % 5 === 0)) || (n % 5 === 0  && !(n % 3 === 0));
```

(untested)

Answer (score 1):

Your second check is wrong:

`if ((n % 3 === 0 || n % 5 === 0) &&**( n % 3 !== 0 && n % 5 !== 0)**)`

Change it to:

`(! (n%3 === 0 && n % 5 === 0 ) )`

Answer (score 1):

This is a short version of `XOR` implementation using conditional statement in javascript

```
if((n % 3 === 0)? (n % 5 !== 0) : (n % 5 === 0)) {
  ...
}
```

or you can also compare in this way, checking when the two conditions, when evaluated as boolean, return different values (one is true and other is false or vice-versa)

```
if( (n % 3 === 0) !==  (n % 5 === 0)) {
  ...
}
```

so this code can be written really short